# Save the "previous" route and navigate back to it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a route table that has a section like as follows:

```
<Route path="/projects" component={ProjectsLayout}>
  <IndexRoute component={Projects} />
  <Route path=":id">
    <IndexRoute component={Contents} />
    <Route path="files/:fileId" component={FileViewer} />
    <Route path="folders/**/:folderId" component={Folder} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

What I want to do is "save" the route before they navigated into the `ProjectsLayout`, so that I can return back to that previous component.

My plan is to watch the path and then go back that many increments, ie:

```
state = { index: 1 };  // index is one so it goes one more than the layout

componentDidMount() {
  this.props.router.listen(this.onRouteChange);
}

onClickExit = () => this.props.router.goBack(this.state.index);
```

However, I can't find an efficient way to maintain the index

Is there a way to do this with `react-router`?

Comment: react-router [Histories](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md) are already there to keep track of this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at browserHistory from react-router?

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md

i apologise that i cannot comment more as i am VERY new to react, but remember seeing this in some documentation

hope it helps even a little